# Export to Hindi Font Not Support in Angular 14+ (using Kendo)

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I hope you are doing well. I'm currently working on an Angular project that uses Kendo UI for exporting content to PDF. However, I'm encountering issues with Hindi font support during the PDF export process.

Here's a snippet of my Angular component:

```
import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './products';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button kendo-button (click)="pdf.saveAs('table.pdf')">
      Save As PDF...
    </button>
    <kendo-pdf-export #pdf paperSize="A4" margin="2cm" [repeatHeaders]="true">
      <div>हेडर इनफो 1</div>
      <div class="pdf-export-only">अधिकारों</div>
      <kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="products">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="आईडी" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="नाम"></kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
    </kendo-pdf-export>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./pdf-styles.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public products: any[] = products;
}
```

Despite my efforts, the Hindi font doesn't seem to be supported properly in the exported PDF. I've ensured that the font is loaded correctly in my application, and it works fine in the browser. However, the issue arises when exporting to PDF.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this font issue and ensure proper Hindi font support in the exported PDF using Kendo UI Angular would be highly appreciated.

I have ensured that the Hindi font is loaded correctly in my application, and it displays properly in the browser. However, when attempting to export to PDF using Kendo UI Angular, the Hindi font doesn't seem to be supported as expected.